# android notification after reboot

Tags: android, notifications

I want to put up a notification in the notification bar that will launch my app when pressed.  While I have no problems doing this, my users want the notification to come up after a reboot as well. They have an app from another vendor that does this.

Everything I can find states that the app must be running for the notification to display.  Any ideas?

Comment: I know the answer from eSniff will work.  But the other app I am talking about has NO running services and the app itself is not running, yet the notification still exists and tapping on it launches the app.

Comment: have you solved this? I am wondering the same way too

Answer (score 12):

You need to add a receiver that launches a Service after a reboot.

In your manifest register for Boot Complete

```
<service android:name="com.meCorp.service.MeCorpServiceClass"/>
...
<receiver android:name="com.meCorp.receiver.MyRebootReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

In your boot receiver, launch a service.

```
public class MyRebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MeCorpServiceClass.class);
          serviceIntent.putExtra("caller", "RebootReceiver");
          context.startService(serviceIntent);
       }
}
```

Here is an example for a service class to run in the background.

```
    public class MeCorpServiceClass extends IntentService{

         @Override
         protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
             String intentType = intent.getExtras().getString("caller");
             if(intentType == null) return;
             if(intentType.Equals("RebootReceiver"))
                  //Do reboot stuff
             //handle other types of callers, like a notification.
         }
     }
```

OR Just use a third party like Urban AirShip, which handles all that for you.

Comment: u have to add permission as well, to receive boot_complete

Comment: @android_hungry Thanks, I just did.

Comment: @eSniff why are you using separate `IntentService` for handling "boot completed stuff"? Is it about threading or any other issue?

Comment: @ilmash I haven't written Android code in 5 years but I'm pretty sure I did that to keep the class small and faster to load at startup and because I was writing this as an optional feature for an Analytics SDK for Android.  It had a number of features that could be turned on or off via the manifest.

Comment: @eSniff well, that may explain it, but nowadays, from my experience, system doesn't care much about starting your services right away. depending on model tested some services ran even 1-2 minutes later than homescreen was ready. nevermind custom OS managers that could forbid any autostart and user has to manually start the app or let it receive intent