# Start my android application *in the background* on boot

Tags: android, background, boot

I am successfully able to start my Android app automatically on boot using BroadcastReceiver with an intent-filter BOOT_COMPLETED. In my onReceive method, I start the launcher activity for my application.

However, I don't want this application to be in the foreground on boot, but I do want it to be on the activity stack. Is there a way to still have the home screen show up on boot, but also have my application starts up. (I don't think I want to use a Service, because my application has UI.)

Comment: Your application can have a UI and a Service together.  If you decide to use a service see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461208/android-notification-after-reboot/8461275

Comment: "However, I don't want this application to be in the foreground on boot, but I do want it to be on the activity stack." -- this makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: By this I mean that the home page may be in the foreground, my app would still be alive, but in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision on weather you should or should not use Service in appliction is independent on weather it has UI or not. All "third party" apps have UI, there is little use of application without at least 1 activity.

So in your case, just use `Service`.

Comment: @lost_bits1110: But, please, don't create a `Service` that is designed to run forever, which is what it feels like you are aiming for.

Comment: In my BroadcastReceiver's onReceive, I have simply used 'startService' instead of 'startActivity'. This seems to accomplish what I need.